# Fastest way to continuously write bitmaps to disk

Tags: java, android

I have an android application and I am capturing every frame produced. I want to save each frame to disk. I know I could do video (i.e. using the MediaRecorder), but this is not what I want.

As you can imagine, writing 30 bitmaps to disk per second is pretty slow...

With the frames being produced at run-time, I do not know in advance how many will be produced.

Here is my write to disk function:

```
public static void store(Bitmap bm, String fileName){
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What is the fastest way to save bitmaps to disk?

Comment: That looks pretty fast. But i wonder where those bitmaps come from.

Comment: @blackapps a YUV image is retrieved from ARCore `Frame.acquireCameraImage()`, converted to jpeg and then converted into a bitmap.

Comment: You cannot convert directly to png?

Comment: Or why not store the yuv to file? Or the jpg? All conversions take time.

Comment: @blackapps could store YUV to file, but the format varies from device to device, so it might be difficult to use later. Using later is not critical at this point, so I might still go with that option, but I'd like to make sure that for now, the `store` function is as quick as possible.

Comment: The time needed for storing to getFilesDir(), getExternalFilesDir() or removable micro sd card will be different. Find out which suits you best.