# how to save multiple bitmaps fastly in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-bitmap

I want to save bitmaps in the gallery.
Currently, I am using the following code:

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap output){
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Imverter/ImverterEffectedImage";
    File dir = new File(filepath);
    if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    String fileName = "Imverter" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    File image = new File(dir, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        output.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It saves one single bitmap efficiently, but in my app, I have to deal with multiple bitmaps, and this method results in the slow output.
I want to store every single bitmap in a different files.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404525/fastest-way-to-continuously-write-bitmaps-to-disk?noredirect=1#comment112124951_63404525

Comment: @blackapps okay, it means that this is the fastest way up untill now, right?